# Как работать с VKRequestListener?

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Доброго времени суток, господа!
Помогите разобраться.

```
 private AccountInfo getAccountInfo() {
        final AccountInfo accountInfo = new AccountInfo();
        VKRequest profileInfo1 = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS, Constants.PHOTO_MAX_ORIG));
        profileInfo1.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
//Do complete stuff
                try {
                    JSONArray responseArray = response.json.getJSONArray(Constants.RESPONSE);
                    JSONObject obj = responseArray.getJSONObject(0);

                    accountInfo.userName = obj.getString(Constants.FIRST_NAME);
                    accountInfo.userLastname = obj.getString(Constants.LAST_NAME);
                    accountInfo.avatarUrl = 

obj.getString(Constants.PHOTO_MAX_ORIG);

tvUserFullName.setText(accountInfo.userName + " " + accountInfo.userLastname); 

                    Log.d(TAG, "Name = " + accountInfo.userName);
                    Log.d(TAG, "LastName = " + accountInfo.userLastname);
                    Log.d(TAG, "avatarURL = " + accountInfo.avatarUrl);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(VKError error) {
//Do error stuff
                Toast.makeText(UserInterface.this, "Не удалось загрузить данные из Вашего аккаунта.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            @Override
            public void attemptFailed(VKRequest request, int attemptNumber, int totalAttempts) {
//I don't really believe in progress
            }
        });
        return accountInfo; null/null/null
    }
```

Проблема в том, что строка

```
return accountInfo;
```

и
`tvUserFullName.setText(accountInfo.userName + " " + accountInfo.userLastname);` выполняется раньше чем 
приходит ответ от сервера

```
accountInfo.userName = obj.getString(Constants.FIRST_NAME);
```

И прога вылетает с  `NullPointerException.`

Answer (score 0):

Вы не сможете заставить синхронный метод немедленно вернуть данные, на получение которых нужно время.

Также вы не можете заставить метод ждать, пока выполняется запрос. Тем паче, что он может и не быть успешным.

Вам надо так переделать логику, чтобы обрабатывать результат запроса только после его исполнения.

Comment: а какие есть способы, методы которые будут срабатывать только при ответе сервера???

Comment: @S.TertJ, при завершении запроса вызываются уже имеющиеся у вас в коде onComplete и onError